# Pivot Table Charts Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a selection of data that shows scores for a group by score 1-10 is it possible to create two charts in one, one that shows the value of the scores in a bar chart and the 2nd that shows the average score overlaid as a line chart. I can create the 1st with no problem, it is the 2nd that I am having problems with.

Comment: What is on the other axis? Average scores over time? How many plot lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is harder than one would think...  Column charts are easy to do this with.  Bar charts on the other hand, do not allow mixing with lines as easily--changing the second series chart type will make the line go horizontally (as I'm sure you've seen), instead of the vertical line you are probably looking for.

If you want a vertical line:

1. Create a second series (in clustered bar) that is just your average repeated once for each category.
2. Right Click on this new series, and Add Trendline (Linear)
3. Set Series Options, Overlap=100%
4. Change fill to No Fill
5. Border Color to No Line